# Linux Memory pages 4KB vs. 8KB?

Tags: linux, memory-management

I am reading the book "Linux Kernel Development" by Robert Love, 3rd edition. In Chapter 12, Memory Management (p. 231), it states:

> Most 32-bit architectures have 4KB pages, whereas most 64-bit architectures have 8KB pages.

My Intel `x86_64` machines and VMs have 4KB pages and I could not find any reference on Google about 8KB memory pages on Linux. There is the concept of huge pages but I don't think that is what the book means when it talks about 8KB pages on 64bit.

So, is that an errata in the book, are there other less common 64-bit architectures that do have 8KB pages, or did that change over time?

**Update:**
I looked at Chapter 19, "Portability", but I am still confused about the quoted sentence. For example, the table 19.4 (p. 392) lists a total of 21 architectures but only **four** of them have a page size of 8KB. Only for `alpha` and `cris` 8KB is the only supported page size, the others additionally support 4KB and more. Four out of 21 does not sound like *most 64-bit architectures* to me.

Additionally, the text explicitly talks about `x86-32` but does not mention `x86-64` and the table 19.4 is also not explicit about 32/64 variants of these architectures.

It appears to me that virtually all architectures use 4KB pages on both 32-bit and 64-bit with the few notable exceptions such as `alpha` and `cris`. In addition, the `h8300` and `m68k` architectures can optionally use 8KB as well. So how does the statement about "most 64-bit architectures" fit into that picture?

Comment: The 2nd edition prefaces your comment with "As you'll see in Chapter 19, "Portability," each architecture enforces its own page size", and Chapter 19 lists the page sizes of ~20 different architectures. Does your edition not have that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have updated my question with my understanding of the portability section.